# How to execute chrome extension by schedule in background js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a question.
I need to execute my extension every some period of time, but I can`t, because my script is executed only when popap is open. I would want it started to work after opening chrome browser.

It`s my manifest.json:

```
"name": "MyExt",
"version": "1.0",
"description": " 'It`s my extension",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/core.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"icons": {
    "128" : "icon.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "ext.png",
    "default_title": "MyExt",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
 },
```

Comment: You need to move that code in the background script core.js.

Comment: Do you mean just without js folder?

Comment: The folder doesn't matter. Just in case, see also the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): the background script runs in a separate hidden background page.

Comment: Just rename my "core.js" to "background.js"?

Comment: File name also doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/#type-AlarmCreateInfo) to execute script by schedule.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you cannot execute the code in time intervals. What you can do is register an `eventListener` in background.js (or whatever you decide to name it) and execute the code you put in there when the event happens(extension is installed, there is an available update either for your extension or for Chrome etc.).

On the link below you can see all the available event listeners:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#events